# Why do we not define the metric on the sequence space as the larget seperation between the sequence?

Tags: metric-spaces

Space consists of the set of all (bounded or unbounded) sequences of complex numbers and the metric $d$ defined by

$$d(x,y)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^j}\frac{|\xi_j-\eta_j|}{1+|\xi_j-\eta_j|}.$$

where $x=(\xi_j)$ and $y=(\eta_j).$

---

I just want to ask *why $d'(x,y)=\text{sup}_{j\in\Bbb{N}}|x_j-y_j|$ is not suitable for the above space?*

---

What can I think that if we take unbounded sequence  then the **sup** would be *infinity*. But I am unable to take down it in an appropriate way.

Comment: Did you mean to write$$d(x,y)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac1{2^{\color{red}j}}\frac{|\xi_j-\eta_j|}{1+|\xi_j-\eta_j|}?$$

Comment: Just take one of the sequences to be unbounded, and the other to be identically $0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I fixed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just lost in the storm of overthinking...although with the help of@saulspatz...Now it's clear.

If $(x_n)$ is unbounded sequence and $(y_n)$ is identically zero, then

$d'(x,y)=\text{sup}_{n\in\Bbb{N}}|x_n-y_n|=\text{sup}_{n\in\Bbb{N}}|x_n|=\infty$,

which is not a real number therefore $d'$ is not well defined and hence  not suitable for said metric space.